# LDNS : Undefined reference to variables ( C++ )

Tags: c++

I'm new to LDNS. I installed [ldns](http://t.signaledue.com/e1t/c/5/f18dQhb0S7lC8dDMPbW2n0x6l2B9nMJW7t5XYg65jBJxW3My3jY1pNgZ4VfD6ll56dS-td4n25b02?si=6576865984643072&pi=4FE7CBE3-30EE-49D8-9154-86536E28FA68&t=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Enlnetlabs%2Enl%2Fprojects%2Fldns%2F) by the method they showed in the README file. I tried using their [sample code](http://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/doc/tutorial1_mx.html) but whenever I compile it using g++ file.cpp I get the following error.

Using virtual box with Ubuntu on MACOS.

```
/tmp/ccxvsMSZ.o: In function `main':
dns.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `ldns_dname_new_frm_str'
dns.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `ldns_resolver_new_frm_file'
dns.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `ldns_resolver_query'
dns.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `ldns_pkt_rr_list_by_type'
dns.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `ldns_rr_list_sort'
dns.cpp:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `ldns_rr_list_print'
dns.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `ldns_rr_list_deep_free'
dns.cpp:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `ldns_pkt_free'
dns.cpp:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `ldns_resolver_deep_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

P.S.:  Tried running code on MAC but got the following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ldns_dname_new_frm_str", referenced from:
      _main in dns-9f53eb.o
  "_ldns_pkt_free", referenced from:
      _main in dns-9f53eb.o
  "_ldns_pkt_rr_list_by_type", referenced from:
      _main in dns-9f53eb.o
  "_ldns_resolver_deep_free", referenced from:
      _main in dns-9f53eb.o
  "_ldns_resolver_new_frm_file", referenced from:
      _main in dns-9f53eb.o
  "_ldns_resolver_query", referenced from:
      _main in dns-9f53eb.o
  "_ldns_rr_list_deep_free", referenced from:
      _main in dns-9f53eb.o
  "_ldns_rr_list_print", referenced from:
      _main in dns-9f53eb.o
  "_ldns_rr_list_sort", referenced from:
      _main in dns-9f53eb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: You need to link against the library that contains those symbols. Identify where that is, and what your compiler's syntax is to link against a library.

Comment: I think while configuring and making the downloaded files, the library would be linked. Doesn't it?

Comment: `g++ file.cpp ` doesn't link any libraries

Answer (score 0):

Specify ldns (`-lldns`) library while compiling.